# Pdf not returning from Aws Lambda, but working fine in local

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, node-pdfkit

I am creating a serverless app in nodejs and using the command "sls deploy" to Aws Cloud. The app function is to send back pdf when accessed through an get endpoint. I am using pdfkit to create pdf content and returning it on GET request. This is working fine in local. However when i deploy the code to aws , i am seeing my function execution is fine (Cloud formation logs says so) , however my pdf is coming back as empty. the below is the pdfkit package which i am using

http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html

please let me know, how i can fix this issue ..

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get('/retrievePdf', (req, res) => {
var doc = new PDFDocument({size: "A4"});
doc.pipe(res);
doc.fontSize(16).text("Sample Pdf").moveDown();
doc.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('listening on port 3000')
});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

Comment: is your lambda under a VPC or any subnet?

Comment: i am using serverless pattern to deploy this node js app .. i believe the pattern just creates an apigateway and lambda function for execution ...

Comment: What's in the execution logs for your lambda? What's in the execution logs for your API's method?

Comment: i am printing a console statement after doc.end() and i see that is printing .. i dont see any errors in lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

PDF generation in Lambda functions can be quite finicky as it typically requires and assumes a number of things from the runtime under which it runs (fonts, OS versions etc).

After some trial and error, in the end my approach to PDF generation in Lambda was to use [wkhtmltopdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf) and upload the binary for it along with my function code, though my use case vastly preferred HTML formatting for the rendered document either way.

Note that in order to return binary documents through API Gateway you have to explicitly map certain content types as binary, else you're going to end up with a base64 encoded string response. An easy way to do this is to use a Serverless plugin such as [serverless-apigw-binary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-apigw-binary) and make sure you set the response content type correctly in your Lambda code.